# Function call works in C but Segfaults in Python when accessing Prosilica GigE Camera with Python using OpenCV

Tags: python, c, opencv, camera, computer-vision

The general problem I am trying ot debug is why a C program can call a function with no problem, but when the same function is called in Python it causes a segfault.

I'm trying to get the Python OpenCV bindings to access an AVT GigE
GC1360H Camera using modules/highgui/src/cap_pvapi.cpp.  I can read
and display frames from the camera flawlessly in C, but when I attempt
to read a frame in Python the interpreter segfaults.  Calling
VideoCapture.open(0) in Python successfully initializes the camera to
Mono8 mode, and watching ifconfig shows data coming in from the
camera.  I can run this same Python code using my v4l webcam instead
of the AVT camera and it works fine.  I am using OpenCV 2.3.1 on
Gentoo Linux 3.2.12 x64. Here is the Python code I am using, running
on Python 2.7.2:

```
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cv2.namedWindow("Cam", 1)
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture()
    capture.open(0) # This successfully opens the Camera and ifconfig
shows data being transferred
    while True:
        img = capture.read()[1] # This is where it segfaults

        cv2.imshow("Cam", img)
        if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27: break

    cv2.destroyWindow("Cam")
```

I attached gdb to the Python interpreter and figured out that it
segfaults on the call to PvCaptureQueueFrame() inside
CvCaptureCAM_PvAPI::grabFrame() in the OpenCV source.  Here is the output from that:

```
alex@Wassenberg ~ $ gdb python GNU gdb (Gentoo 7.3.1 p2) 7.3.1 Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html> This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details. This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu". For bug reporting instructions, please see: <http://bugs.gentoo.org/>... Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python...(no debugging symbols found)...done. (gdb) run ./pyview.py Starting program: /usr/bin/python ./pyview.py process 8921 is executing new program: /usr/bin/python2.7 [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled] [New Thread 0x7fffe3c10700 (LWP 8929)] [New Thread 0x7fffe340f700 (LWP 8930)] [New Thread 0x7fffe2c0e700 (LWP 8931)] [New Thread 0x7fffe240d700 (LWP 8932)] [Thread 0x7fffe240d700 (LWP 8932) exited] [New Thread 0x7fffe240d700 (LWP 8933)] [Thread 0x7fffe240d700 (LWP 8933) exited] [New Thread 0x7fffe240d700 (LWP 8940)] [Thread 0x7fffe240d700 (LWP 8940) exited] [New Thread 0x7fffe240d700 (LWP 8941)] [New Thread 0x7fffe1c0c700 (LWP 8942)] [New Thread 0x7fffe0eb9700 (LWP 8948)] [New Thread 0x7fffdbfff700 (LWP 8949)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00007ffff007c8ea in PvCaptureQueueFrame () from /usr/local/lib/libPvAPI.so (gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff007c8ea in PvCaptureQueueFrame () from /usr/local/lib/libPvAPI.so
#1  0x00007ffff55dd123 in CvCaptureCAM_PvAPI::grabFrame() () from /usr/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3
#2  0x00007ffff55dde31 in cvGrabFrame () from /usr/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3
#3  0x00007ffff55dde4d in cv::VideoCapture::grab() () from /usr/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3
#4  0x00007ffff55ddaf2 in cv::VideoCapture::read(cv::Mat&) () from /usr/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so.2.3
#5  0x00007ffff6b355c5 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
#6  0x00007ffff7afdfdc in PyEval_EvalFrameEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#7  0x00007ffff7aff88d in PyEval_EvalCodeEx () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#8  0x00007ffff7aff9a2 in PyEval_EvalCode () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#9  0x00007ffff7b19afc in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#10 0x00007ffff7b1a930 in PyRun_FileExFlags () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#11 0x00007ffff7b1b50f in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#12 0x00007ffff7b2c823 in Py_Main () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
#13 0x00007ffff74902ad in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#14 0x00000000004008a9 in _start () (gdb)
```

Any insight into this problem would be appreciated.  Ultimately what this question boils down to is why C can call grabFrame() with no problem but Python segfaults.  I am inclined to think the
problem is the way that the Python bindings to C are generated, but I
am not familiar with how OpenCV does this. Any ideas why grabFrame() and PvCaptureQueueFrame() would work fine in C but not in Python?

For reference here is the C program that could successfully read the AVT camera:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
      printf("Press ESC to exit\n");
      cvNamedWindow( "First Example of PVAPI Integrated", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
      CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture( CV_CAP_PVAPI );
      assert( capture != NULL );

      IplImage* frame;

      while(1)
      {
            frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

            if(!frame) break;
            cvShowImage( "First Example of PVAPI Integrated", frame);
            char c = cvWaitKey(50);
            if( c == 27) break;
      }
      cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
      cvDestroyWindow( "First Example of PVAPI Integrated" );
}
```

Compiled with gcc 4.5.3-r2:

> gcc -I/usr/include/opencv -o main ./main.c -lopencv_core
>   -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video
>   -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect
>   -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, the only difference between the C code and the Python code was the argument passed to cvCreateCameraCapture()(capture.open() in Python).  Passing a 0 into this function(as I did in Python) should make it scan for any video device OpenCV supports, which it did.  Passing CV_CAP_PVAPI(as I did in C) should limit this search to only Prosilica devices.  While these should yeild exactly the same results(they both found the same camera), when passing in a 0 the camera did not get initialized and wasn't ready to accept tPvFrames in the queue.  Passing an 800 into capture.open() fixed the problem, as 800 is the value of CV_CAP_PVAPI.